# Why margin loss is used in Capsule Network instead of Cross Entropy loss?

Tags: deep-learning, loss-function

I'm reading the [Capsule Network paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.09829) proposed by Hinton. I'm not sure why the margin loss is used instead of the cross entropy loss. Any intuitive explaination for this?

Comment: paper reference please..?

Comment: As @NikosM. says, please provide the relevant link(s) in similar questions (added it myself, Νίκο...)

Comment: my understanding (after a quick read of the paper) is that margin loss is suitable, as vector length represents probability of existence, and margin loss is such that "*..the top-level capsule for digit class k to have a long instantiation vector if and only if that digit is present in the image.*" (quoted)

Comment: ["*..the cross entropy is the average number of bits needed to encode data coming from a source with distribution p when we use model q*"](https://machinelearningmastery.com/cross-entropy-for-machine-learning/), CE as a loss function does not capture the semantics of vectors as used in Capsules

Comment: hmm i see, the vector lenght represents the probability of existence, this is important information